# Can you access screen display's DPI settings in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, dpi, display-dpi

Is there a way to access the screen display's DPI settings in Silverlight?  If so, how?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can. Its pretty protected.